# determine time zone from zip code in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

This is my first time trying to use a lambda function, please help me determine what I'm doing incorrectly. I wrote a function to output time zones based on zip codes. The function works but not sure how to implement it as a lambdas function to create a new column in my dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
from pyzipcode import ZipCodeDatabase
zcdb = ZipCodeDatabase()

def find_tz(zip_code):
    try:
        tz = zcdb[zip_code].timezone
        return tz
    except:
        return '?'

data = [['Jane','92804'], ['Bob','75014'], ['Ashley','07650']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Contact','Zip'])
```

```
in: df
out: 
    Contact  Zip
0   Jane     92804
1   Bob      75014
2   Ashley   07650
```

Do note that that zip code column data are strings, since US zip codes have leading 0s.

Me testing that the function I wrote works on values from df:

```
in: print(find_tz(df.loc[0,'Zip']))
print(find_tz(df.loc[1,'Zip']))
print(find_tz(df.loc[2,'Zip']))

out: 
-8
-6
-5
```

My attempt at using a lambda function to create a new Timezone column, and the incorrect result I am getting:

```
in: df = df.assign(Timezone = lambda x: find_tz(x.Zip))
df

out: 
    Contact  Zip    Timezone
0   Jane     92804  ?
1   Bob      75014  ?
2   Ashley   07650  ?
```

My desired resulting dataframe would look like:

```
    Contact  Zip    Timezone
0   Jane     92804  -8
1   Bob      75014  -6
2   Ashley   07650  -5
```

ETA: when I changed my find_tz() function to something like concatenating the input with another string of text, the lambda worked as I expected, so I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

Comment: Try `df = df.assign(Timezone = x.Zip.apply(find_tz))`

Comment: @DaniMesejo hah.. just added back the `lambda x` part and it worked... i would like to know why my original code didn't work though, so i can learn why it failed! thanks!

`df = df.assign(Timezone = lambda x: x.Zip.apply(find_tz))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:
`df['Timezone'] = df.Zip.apply(find_tz)`

When you call `lambda x: find_tz(x.Zip)` the find_tz function is passed a Pandas series not the individual zip codes

Comment: I see, so I didn't actually even need `lambda`. How come when I defined my `find_tz()` function differently (like `tz = zip_code + " XXX"` it gave me a column of concatenated strings like I expected? (ex: "92804 XXX")

Comment: When the apply calls find_tz the argument zip_code is a pandas series. You can use zip_code + ‘ XXX’ on a pandas series so the call works. For the case above the call in the try block fails as the look up zcdb[zip_code] expected an integer